# Submit form cross site with jquery ajax and then email it

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms, cross-domain

I have registration form which needs to be sent to a third party software and then I need to email the contents of the form after the successful submit.

I am using jquery ajax form plugin to submit the form and then calling jquery ajax on success. I have to use the plugin because I need to send attachments in the form and the jquery serialize function doesn't include files. The form submits successfully cross site but the email script doesn't run.

**Following is the code:**

```
var options = {
            success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
            // other available options: 
            url: 'url to third party software',         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
            type: 'post'        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        };
        // bind to the form's submit event 
        $('#main-form').ajaxSubmit(options);

        // post-submit callback 

        function showResponse() {
            var newCustomerForm = jQuery("#main-form").serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url to email script on local server",
                action: addCustomer,
                data: newCustomerForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#form-container').html('<h3>Thank you. Your Online Application has been successfully submitted. </h3>');
                }
            });
        }




//php email sending script
    function addCustomer()
    {

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
        {

                    $str .= "<b> ".str_replace('_',' ',$key).":</b> $value<br>";
         }

        if(isset($_FILES['file1']))
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['file1']['name']));
            $attachments[$s] = WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$_FILES["file1"]["name"];
        }

                                }


    ////////////////email settings///////////////////////////////////////////   
        $emailTo = 'email address';


                                add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
    $emailSent = true;
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
```

Comment: please post the script for sending email

Comment: @krishna Added the email script